# Rendering an interactive timetable with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I am creating a website using JavaScript/ASP.NET/C#/CSS/HTML/Compact SQL server.

I have the majority of the site created and a basic database design which I would like to test out fully.

To do this I would like to create a JavaScript/JQuery front end. The basic functionality I wish to have is the exact same as Google Calendar (to begin with at least).

I'd ideally like the user to be able to select a number of times, via drag and drop, when the user drags and drops to certain times they are prompted for a name for the task.

The user then clicks submit and the data is saved in the database - with the users ID, the event start time/duration and the name of the event.

My question is quite vague, but what would be the best way to go about this ? I know exactly what I would like to do, but my problems are :

- Creating an interactive timetable using JQuery/JavaScript - is there any existing renderings of this I could work from, with a similar database intergration/idea?
- How can I save all of this data in the database? If it was a form I could just pass in data, but as it isn't I'm not sure how this could be done?

Thanks very much, if any of my details are too vague then please ask questions and I will elaborate in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the calendar structure, but you can possibly use [jQuery Grid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5), although I recomend you to generate the calendar structure and the initial data server side and, maybe load it with AJAX.

All of the other interaction can be made with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), including drag & drop funcionality with AJAX to store the updates to the data.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what the jQGrid plugin has to do with a calendar ?

Comment: It may be used to generate the table structure of the calendar, but I think it's not the best idea to generate it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

There are already some jQuery plugins which can do what you are asking :

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) (be sure to check all the demo at the bottom of the page and more specifically [the drag and drop one](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/selectable.html))
[Frontier Calendar](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/)
[DhtmlxSchedule](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) (not jquery but probably the most advanced)

At least looking at the code of those plugins could be a good start if you don't want to use one of them.

> How can I save all of this data in the database? If it was a form I
>   could just pass in data, but as it isn't I'm not sure how this could
>   be done?

You just have to make an ajax request with your data. No need to use a form, simply send a post or get request to your processing page.